# How to avoid manual entering of input file, when .exe file is run from Matlab?

Tags: matlab, input, executable

I am using a `trans.exe` file, which when run asks for a parameter (=input) file. If I run `trans.exe` using Matlab, then how can I directly give the parameter file inside the program without being prompted by Matlab to type it manually each time `trans.exe` is run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`system('"C:\path_name\trans.exe" < "C:\path_name\input_trans_parameter_file.txt"');`

The following command line used in above `system` function directly uses the name of the input file stored in `input_trans_parameter_file.txt`.

**< "C:\path_name\input_trans_parameter_file.txt"**

Answer (score 1):

If your executable doesn't have the ability to accept command-line parameters, then your only option is to invoke a call which pipes stuff to the stdin of your executable (under Linux, this would be something like `!echo "blah blah blah" | my_executable`).  I don't know if this technique works from Matlab, though.